# How do you skip a service call in a rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Im writing a test for this service.

```
  def run
    sort_offers(product).each do |product_code|
      ......
      offer.update(poduct_params)
      Importer::Partner.get_details(product_code).new
    end
  end
```

It's calling a service which in some cases will override the values that were saved when running `offer.update(product_prams)`. How would I go about skipping the service call within my test?

Here is the example of my test

```
 context 'is valid' do
  .... .....
  before do
    Importer::ProductCodes(product).run
  end
  it ......
end
```

Comment: Can you mock the service call with Mocha? That's the standard answer to "how do I test around an annoying system call?"

Comment: `s/Mocha/any mocking library of your choice/g`

Comment: @Phlip I see, thank you

Comment: Just to clearify: You want to write a spec for your `run` method, but you do want `Importer::Partner.get_details(product_code).new` to do nothing (aka stub calls to it)?

Comment: @spickermann Yes that is correct

Answer (score 1):

I would stub `Importer::Partner.get_details` to return a `double` that responds to `new`:

```
context 'is valid' do
  before do
    allow(Importer::Partner).to receive(:get_details).and_return(double(new: nil))
  end  

  # it ...
end
```

Depending on your needs you might want to add an expectation that the mock was called with the correct parameters and that `new` was actually called on the mock too:

```
context 'is valid' do
  let(:mock) { double(new: nil) }

  before do
    allow(Importer::Partner).to receive(:get_details).and_return(double(new: nil))
  end  

  it "calls the service" do
    an_instance.run

    expect(Importer::Partner).to have_received(:get_details).with(
      foo: 'bar' # the arguments you would expect
    )
    expect(mock).to have_received(:new)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

RSpec has a very capable stubbing and mocking library built in ([rspec mocks](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-8/docs)).

```
require 'spec_helper'

module Importer
  class Partner
    def self.get_details(product_code)
      "original return value"
    end
  end
end

class FooService
  def self.run
    Importer::Partner.get_details('bar')
  end
end

RSpec.describe FooService do
  let(:partner_double) { class_double("Importer::Partner") }

  before do
    stub_const("Importer::Partner", partner_double)
    allow(partner_double).to receive(:get_details).and_return 'our mocked value'
  end

  it "creates a double for the dependency" do
    expect(FooService.run).to eq 'our mocked value'
  end
end
```

[`class_double`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/verifying-doubles/using-a-class-double) creates a double for the class and you can set the return values by using `.expect` and `.allow` and the mocking interface. This is quite useful since you can stub out the `new` or `intialize` methods to return a double or spy.

[`stub_constant`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-8/docs/mutating-constants/stub-defined-constant) will reset the constant to its previous value when the spec is done.

That said you can avoid the use of `stub_constant` by using constructor injection in your services:

```
class PhotoImportService

  attr_accessor :client, :username

  def initialize(username, api_client: nil)
    @username = username
    @client = api_client || APIClient.new(ENV.fetch('API_KEY'))
  end

  def run
    client.get_photos(username)
  end
end
```